# Why is this procedural macro panicing

Tags: rust, tokenize, dsl, rust-proc-macros

I am using proc macros to parse a given input into a Node tree, for debugging purposes I want to stringify and print the output to see if I am successfully converting to RPN, my current function:

```rust
use proc_macro::*;
#[proc_macro]
pub fn symbolic(body: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    // ---shunting yard---
    let mut stack : Vec<TokenTree> = vec![];
    let mut que : Vec<TokenTree> = vec![];

    for tt in body.into_iter(){
        match tt {
            TokenTree::Ident(_) => que.push(tt),
            TokenTree::Punct(_) => {
                while precedence(Some(&tt)) <= precedence(stack.last()){
                    que.push(stack.pop().unwrap());
                }
                stack.push(tt)
            },
            TokenTree::Literal(_) => que.push(tt),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
    while let Some(op) = stack.pop() {
        que.push(op);
    }

    println!(stringify!(output_que));
    "fn answer() -> u32 { 42 }".parse().unwrap()
}
fn precedence(tt: Option<&TokenTree>) -> usize{
    if let Some(TokenTree::Punct(punct)) = tt{
        match punct.as_char() {
            '^' => 3,
            '/' | '*' => 2,
            '-' | '+' => 1,
            _ => 0
        }
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

gives me an error

```
error: proc macro panicked
 --> src\main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     symbolic!(x^2 + 2*x)
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: message: called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value
```

which I do not understand as this should be outputting an empty token stream since `TokenStream::new() -> TokenStream { TokenStream(None) }` is this not acceptable, if not I do not understand why. I changed this to the example given in the rust book `"fn answer() -> u32 { 42 }".parse().unwrap()` and still the same error so I don't know what?

Comment: You have several `unwraps` in your code, to get better debugging output you could convert them to `.expcect("where it did fail or why")` and you'd know which of them returned `None`

Comment: You should also only post one question per SO question.

Comment: thank-you  :) I'm hoping the unwrap is safe if the ```precedence``` function takes an option as its argument instead of the TokenTree. what are your thoughts?

Comment: also @cafce25: "You should also only post one question per SO question." I  will bear this in mind in the future. I just feel like I've been asking a lot of questions because I've been dipping into unfamiliar grounds with the macros and CAS / parsing techniques as its not something I have a lot of experience writing.

Comment: Adding yet more questions via an edit is not really 'bearing this in mind in the future' If the questions seem to small or insignificant to be posted on their own, it's probably because they are. See [tour] and [ask]

Comment: In all fairness, I feel neither question to be Insignificant but I feel like the two may be related, like is the compiler acting in this way because the unwrap is unsafe? if so what can I change about the design of my code, anyway, I will change the question into a single question somewhere else

Comment: Use `match` or `?` to handle/forward errors instead as recommended in the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html?highlight=unwrap#shortcuts-for-panic-on-error-unwrap-and-expect).

Comment: something like ```if let Some(punct) = stack.pop(){ que.push() }``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro doesn't work because you never push anything to `stack`
but here:

```rust
while precedence(&tt) <= precedence(stack.last().unwrap()){
    que.push(stack.pop().unwrap());
```

You `unwrap` as if `stack.pop` or `stack.last` was guaranteed to return `Some`.

Comment: aaa I'm so dumb that's frustrating that's from when I migrated the code to macro's instead of string parsing